# How to display non-UPPERCASE blocks of text in iOS 7 Settings area?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In iOS, it's common to use [PSGroupSpecifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/preferencesettings/conceptual/settingsapplicationschemareference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html) in your Settings .plist files, with the Title attribute containing (usually localized) text, when you're trying to display a lot of text to the end-user. Such as in the text of acknowledgements, licensing, privacy policies, etc.

In iOS 7, Title text is rendered ALL UPPERCASE, which looks fine displayed in your normal Settings menus (screenshot #1 below), but terrible in areas where you're using it as described above, for large blocks of text (screenshot #2 below).

Is there any other way to display large blocks of text, where you retain control over the capitalization in the app? (FWIW, I've filed a bug report in radar: #15158823)

**Works OK when used as intended:**

[image]

**Not so good:**

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised apple do this, since currently we have a header "ICLOUD" in the iOS 7 settings app, and they're normally very protective of their lower case i's

Comment: Did you come to any solution on this? I've been trying to achieve it as well and I have seen apps that do it, so it's possible somehow.

Comment: @Rick Nope, nothing so far. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `Title` attribute, use the `FooterText` attribute.

i.e. instead of

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>
... Lots of text ...
    </string>
</dict>
```

use

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
    <key>FooterText</key>
    <string>
... Lots of text ...
    </string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Same here, I am using title & footerText. Title is capitalized (which is fine) and FooterText seems correct.